# Encrypt connection String IIS 7

Tags: encryption, tfs, web-config, connection-string

I am using TFS 2017 Realese definition to deploy my website, My password and username enviromental variables are hidden but when the connection string is passed Web.config file shows the password and the username how can encrypt the Connection sctring in web.config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working using @Arman answer but had to modify it a bit, i had to specify the site number by default its 1 which is a different website check this link on how to find your website number. [link](http://bvs-sharepoint.blogspot.ie/2014/11/how-to-encrypt-webconfig-in-sharepoint.html)

```
%%windir%%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/" -site "2"
```

In my case the site was number 2. Also you have to run the command prompt as Administrator.

Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can run this command in a command prompt(cmd.exe):

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/SampleApplication"
```

Where SampleApplication is the name of your application in IIS
See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but i cant get this command to work.

Comment: I got it working but had to modify a bit. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

To encrypt the Connection string in web.config file, TFS  build task could not do this. It's more related to IIS. Suggest you take a look at this blog: [Encrypting connectionStrings in Web.Config using the NetFrameworkConfigurationKey in an IIS Web Farm scenario](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2014/10/28/encrypting-connectionstrings-in-web-config-using-the-netframeworkconfigurationkey-in-an-iis-web-farm-scenario/)

---

You could try to replace the specific value in the web.config through [**Replace Token task**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) during  release in VSTS. Sample screenshot:

[image]

> For this configuration of Replace Token task, it can replace #{con}#
>   to the con variable value (Create a variable (variable name: con) in
>   Variable tab of build definition) for all .config files (have #{con}#
>   code) in $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) location.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="#{con}#" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I have replace token task to replace the connectionString with env variable of the release definition Should i just create another task ?

Comment: @WojtekT Sorry for the misunderstanding for your original question. This task will not encrypt the Connection sctring in web.config file. Your question seems not related to TFS.  TFS could not do this, it's more related to IIS. Not familiar with  that area, suggest you take a look at this similar question: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2014/10/28/encrypting-connectionstrings-in-web-config-using-the-netframeworkconfigurationkey-in-an-iis-web-farm-scenario/

Answer (score 0):

[image]You have to browse aspnet_regiis and then executing the command with pef and pdf commands along with section name and the path of the webconfig file.